# Energy function not returning value

Tags: python, image, numpy, energy

I have created an energy function in python, which I am applying to a png image. However, I am not getting a returned energy value when I enter the parameters. Can anyone see why this is? Thank you!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

img=mpimg.imread('Image.png')
#plt.imshow(img)
#plt.show()

im=np.array(img


def E_generator(beta, eta, h):
    """Generate energy function E and localized version of E.
        E = h * \sum{x_i} - beta * \sum{x_i x_j} - eta * \sum{x_i y_i}
    """
    def E(x, y):
        """Calculate energy for matrices x, y.
        """
        # sum of products of neighboring paris {xi, yi}
        xxm = np.zeros_like(x)
        xxm[:-1, :] = x[1:, :]  # down
        xxm[1:, :] += x[:-1, :]  # up
        xxm[:, :-1] += x[:, 1:]  # right
        xxm[:, 1:] += x[:, :-1]  # left
        xx = np.sum(xxm * x)
        xy = np.sum(x * y)
        xsum = np.sum(x)
        return h * xsum - beta * xx - eta * xy

     return E

y = np.array(img)
x = np.array(y)

E_generator(0,1,1)
```

Then output returns with: ".E>"

Comment: `E_generator` returns the `E` function. Who calls `E`?

Comment: It came out with "E---function---etc" just stack wouldnt let me print the whole statement

Answer (score 2):

Your function E_generator returns a function (E); to get your result you need to call that function, so you could do something like:

```
print E_generator(0,1,1)(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you! This returned a result of 0, which is not a value I was looking for... The array for my image comes out as
'(300, 300, 3)' I would like to reshape it to be only 300x300. I have tried 'np.reshape(im, 300)' but it says the total array size must be unchanged. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: assuming last dimension is rgb you could just take the mean along that axis img.mean(axis=2) If you want a 'proper' mean then you would have to (img[:,:,0]**2 + img[:,:,1]**2 + img[:,:,2]**2)""0.5 If you don't want to merge the colours in some way then you need to explain how you want to shrink the dimension of your image

Comment: PS if you generate E with (0,1,1) and run it on x = y = img then it will just return sum(img) - sum(img * img) the matplotlib site says it converts RGB uint8 to float32 scaled 0.0 to 1.0